# How to view customer count by transaction count in OLAP using mdx or how to reverse view dimension and measures

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have a sales transaction fact table and customer dimension table. I have transaction-count as a measure.

I want my report as:

```
No. of Time Transaction doing   Customers    Transactions
1                                10                10
2                                6                 12
3-6                              5                 ??
```

How can i achieve this in OLAP using mdx or even using excel but mainitaining pivot table structure.

Comment: What is 3-6? Do you want customer count or distinct count of customers based on transaction fact table?

Comment: 3 - 6 means with 3 to 6 transcation count. Obviously distinct customer-count. Report answers this questions: how many customers has transaction count 1/2/3-6 and how many transaction they do.

Comment: distinct count of customers based on transaction fact table.

Comment: See i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create measures like this:

```
With
Member [Measures].[Customers with 1 transaction] as
Sum(
    existing [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].Members,
    IIF(
        [Measures].[TransactionCount] = 1,
        1,
        NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: That works for customer count. Now for transaction Count for 1 and 2 we can multiply 1*customer-count and 2* customer-count. But what for 2-3 how to find how many transactions customer with 2-3 transaction count did ??

Comment: What about: IIF([Measures].[TransactionCount] = 1,[Measures].[TransactionCount],NULL) ??

Comment: Thanks you saved my day. Finally i also discovered that can also be done by creating Customer_View View with customerid and transaction-count in warehouse. and bringing that view as dimension in OLAP and only creating customer-count and transaction-count measures and relating them by customer id. Which only requires to create standard measures hence improves performance.

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark it answered if the issue is resolved.

Comment: a little modified version of yours worked for me.                                        
    count(filter(EXISTING[Customer].[CustomerID].[CustomerID],
    [Measures].[Total Transaction]=1))